# Delete multiple views at once from a sharepoint list

Tags: rest, sharepoint, power-automate

I have sharepoint list with over 800 views and i need to delete most of them but not all.
Removing 1 by one will take hours and i am looking for a quiker way to do it.
I want to remove views that include a some key-words.

- I tried looking over the rest api for sharepoint... there is a view but i cant make it work. Cant get the path to delete it.
- I tried using power automate to run a script to delete the views but i dont have a delete view option, only a get view id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a GET request to identify all view ids and loop through those and delete each view. Since these are 800 views you might require a couple of runs. With a $filter query parameter with the not equals operator (ne) you can ignore that single view (based on for example the title field).

Below is an example

URI first request

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('@{variables('ListName')}')/Views?$filter=Title ne 'All Items'&$select=Id
```

URI second HTTP request

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('@{variables('ListName')}')/Views('@{item()['Id']}')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly.
Ended up using " $filter=substringof('21',Title) " to filter my views and managed to delet all ~300 views that contain 21 in the Title.

Answer (score 0):

As you gave Power Automate as a way you used to try and answer your problem, I will try and give another way.

For quick scripting, PowerShell (PnP.PowerShell) is well known to use for your SharePoint needs, but for speed and performance, I like to use the chrome extension "SP Editor". This extension adds a new tab in your Chrome dev tools on a SharePoint site with a PnPJS Console, authenticated and ready to used with the library @pnp/sp.

With this context out of the box, you can begin scripting extremely rapidly, while using all features available from the @pnp/sp library.

Among such features, batching is possible, and truely recommended for such cases

For example, something like that:

```js
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";

(async () => {

  const views = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Documents").views.top(2000)()
  const viewsToDelete = views.filter(({ Title }) => Title.match(/my beautiful regex/i))
  
  let batch = sp.web.createBatch()
  let batchSize = 0

  for (const view of viewsToDelete) {
    sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Documents").views.getById(view.Id).inBatch(batch).delete()
    if (batchSize++ > 90) {
      await batch.execute()
      batchSize = 0
      batch = sp.web.createBatch()
    }
  }

  await batch.execute()

})().catch(console.log)
```

This would be able to delete views ~90 by ~90 that match a certain regex on your list named `Documents` right now.

Hope this helps.